# Python: Extracting specific rows from csv as list

Tags: python, csv, parsing

Probably a repost but I can't find a solution that works in my case.

I have a .csv file with an id number associated to a string like this:

```
0   |   ABC
1   |   DEF
   ...
100 |   XYZ
```

I would like to extract the row with an ID number `x` and append it to a list, so ideally something like:

```
with open('myfile.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    results.append([row for idx, row in enumerate(reader) if idx[0] == x)])
```

this solution does not appear to work as it tells me that the "`iterator should return strings, not bytes`" despite the fact that I though I opened it in byte mode

Comment: Any reason for `'rb'` mode?

Comment: @Austin that's because I kept getting that binary error.. I think that read the file in binary mode, doesn't it? I could be wrong

Comment: Also, if your `csv` file indeed does contain the specified characters, you need to set the `delimiter` flag to whatever you need it to (in this case, `|`), since it defaults to `,`

Comment: @dennlinger omg I think that fixed it... boy do I feel dumb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use pandas to read the csv-file into a dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
sourceinput = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv')

outputlist = sourceinput['id'].loc[sourceinput['id'] == <value_you_need>].tolist()
```